# Trying to deploy laravel via Github actions

Tags: laravel, deployment, github-actions

I'm trying to deploy a laravel webapp through Github Actions but I'm stucked on this error:

```
2022/07/21 19:58:13 ssh.ParsePrivateKey: ssh: no key found
scp file to server.
drone-scp error:  error copy file to dest: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, error message: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none], no supported methods remain
```

I've verified all steps of some tutorials, and I can't find the error. Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your GitHub Action did not found the *private* key, like in [`appleboy/ssh-action` issue 6](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action/issues/6):

> Open the file locally, copy its contents (it'll start with `---BEGIN RSA KEY` something) then go to your repo settings, add secret and paste the contents there.

Or:

> in my own situation the problem was solved by copying the entire content of `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa`.
> Starting from and including the comment section `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` ....... to `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

Comment: yessssss!!!! .. that was it!!! thank you! :)